# No Such Element Exception With Loop

Tags: java

I am using this code, and for some reason, I'm getting a No Such Element Exception...

numCompanies is being imported from the keyboard and is showing up right and portfolio is an array with [numCompanies][4].

Can anyone figure out why?

```
for(int i = 0; i < numCompanies; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Stock #" + (i+1) + ": ");
    String stockData = kbReader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\n\n hi" + stockData);
    Scanner stockLine = new Scanner(stockData);
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        portfolio[i][j] = stockLine.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `stockData` doesn't always have 4 substrings separated by an space.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason nextLine would always skip stock #1 and I created another Scanner object and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but probably `stockLine.next();` is called even though there is no element left. So maybe this could help:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    if( stockLine.hasNext() ) {
        portfolio[i][j] = stockLine.next();
    }
    else
    {
        portfolio[i][j] = 0; // or whatever you want it to be by default
    }
}
```

This will solve the error message but not the fault.

Comment: You should use `hasNext()`, not catching the exeception

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a single string to a `Scanner` object, but I would say there's a better way of doing this.

If you want to simply read in the input for each value in the string, separated by spaces, then use `split()`:

```
String stockData = kbReader.nextLine();
String[] data = stockData.split(" ");
if (data.length != 4) {
    System.err.println("Bad data value found!");
} else {
    //run your loop
}
```